# Nginx + Squid + Privoxy + Tor to reverse proxy and protect connecting ips?

Tags: nginx, proxy, squid, tor

I'm looking for some help about how to setup this stack:

**User => site.com => nginx => squid => privoxy => tor => site.net**

So basically, I will have nginx+squid+privoxy+tor on my vps, my domain is site.com and I would like to reverse proxy site.net.

The goal should be that if I have on site.com the ip 1.1.1.1, site.net should see only the IP of the tor exit nodes, not the site.com ip.

What Im trying to do without success is that I need to force nginx to use only the squid port, which is connected to 8 privoxy instances, which are connected to 8 tor instances, to diversify the ips connecting to site.net

I've tried several guides on the net including:

1. **terminal28.com/anonymity-online-how-to-install-and-configure-squid3-tor-privoxy-debian-ubuntu-linux/**
2. **evilzone.org/anonymity/setup-your-own-proxy-with-squidprivoxytor-on-debian-like-distros-(tutorial)/**
3. **wiki.vpsget.com/index.php/Squid%2BPrivoxy%2BTor**
4. **mightycomputers.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/recently-i-foun/**

I would like to learn how this works for personal knowledge and 100% legal usage.

Also checked this old github project, with a nginx patch, but didnt worked:

**github.com/Lem/nginx-to-tor**
Which is somehow what I would like to reach.

I used mainly Ubuntu 14.04 and debian 7, both 64bit.
I stuck mainly on the part when I try to force nginx to use the squid port (3128 as example) and it gives an error.

As explained here: **github.com/Lem/nginx-to-tor/blob/master/frontend/nginx-http_proxy.patch**

If I use my browser to connect directly to squid, it works as it should.

**Thanks to all who might help me a bit.**

Comment: Can you post your nginx vhost config for site.com?  You shouldn't need any type of patching, just set up nginx as a [reverse proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) to squid and let squid handle all the privoxy/tor communication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `http://www.delegate.org/delegate` for that.
I start it with `/opt/dg9_9_13/bin/dg9_9_13 -v ADMIN="mail@host.tld" -P8118 SERVER=http://url.onion SOCKS=localhost:9050/-r PERMIT="*:*:*" AUTHORIZER="-dgauth{user:pass}"`